# Is it possible to downgrade kernel on Ubuntu 21.10 to something lower then 5.13x?

Tags: kernel, downgrade

When I type `apt-cache search linux-generic` it gives me list of 5.13x only. Does it mean that I can't downgrade to something like 5.4? By the way on some linux distro I've seen a GUI utility to deal with kernel versions (Manjaro probably), as I got it there is no such on Ubuntu, at least currently.

Comment: Why do you want to downgrade? Is there any specific issue with the current kernel?

Comment: As above. This sound like a X-Y problem. So, what exactly are you trying to fix that you think is fixable by using an older kernel?

Comment: Are you sure about your details?  Ubuntu 21.04 uses the 5.11 kernel, the 5.13 is used by Ubuntu 21.10  (*so your details are incorrect for a Ubuntu install; are you using Pop OS or other non-Ubuntu, or have made changes to your system?*).  There are also a number of OEM kernels available (they get chosen for your if the installer recognizes your hardware will benefit from them), but I'd check your details.

Comment: @Archisman Panigrahi about the same problems through all Ubuntu flavors and other distors (Fedora, Manjaro...) with any DE. After suspend desktop doesn't react on clicks or/and network devices not found.

Comment: @guiverc right, I meant 21.10.

Answer (score 5):

- You can pick all available kernels at the grub prompt.
- you can set grub to use a specific kernel if available
- you can install more kernels.

The concept of "downgrading" does not apply here (you do not replace a kernel with another; you add kernels or delete kernels from your system (when you logged into the kernel you want to use)).

The tool you mentioned is probably UKUU (Ubuntu Kernel Update Utility) but is no longer FREE so got removed. Have a look at [mainline](https://github.com/bkw777/mainline) (that is a new version of UKUU):

> Features

- Fetches the list of available kernels from the Ubuntu Mainline PPA
- Optionally watches and displays notifications when a new kernel update is available
- Downloads and installs packages automatically
- Display available and installed kernels conveniently
- Install/Uninstall kernels from gui
- For each kernel, the related packages (headers & modules) are installed or uninstalled at the same time

> Installation [using PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Ecappelikan/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mainline
```

[image]